# Exception not handled by Dispatchers UnhandledException handler when throwing exception in Dispatcher.Invoke statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a question regarding the `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` static property. If my understanding is correct this property should return the dispatcher associated with the thread. I thought if I call `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` twice on the same thread I would receive the same Dispatcher instance. Is this true?

I ask this question because I have come across the following. On the startup of my (huge) application I register a Dispatcher exception handler on the main thread like this:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += UnhandledDispatcherExceptionHandler;
```

Later on a different thread I have tried to throw an exception like this:

```
Action exception = () =>
{
    throw new Exception("myExceptionText");
};
myDispatcherInstance.Invoke(exception);
```

Where I have set `myDispatcherInstance` to `myDispatcherInstance` from within the main thread, but from another but later executed point in the code.

So my question is whether the instance that I received from `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` could be different from the one that I received in the first place. In the debugger I saw that `myDispatcherInstance.UnhandledException` is not null but nevertheless the exception does not end up in the `myDispatcherInstance` function but instead is only 'caught' in the domain exception handler:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledDomainExceptionHandler;
```

Or could there be that the `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledExceptionhandler` is correct but for another reason the domain exception handler is triggered and the dispatcher exception handler simple does not fire in this case? If so, what is the reason?

Comment: `In the debugger I saw that myDispatcherInstance.UnhandledException is not null but nevertheless the exception does not end up in the myDispatcherInstance ` Are you saying that it doesn't end up in the `if` clause but skips to the `else` clause? In other words, the line `myDispatcherInstance.Invoke(exception)` is never reached?

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear. No it never ended up in the else statement. The dispatcher is not null, even the `myDispatcherInstance.UnhandledException` event property is not null.

Comment: It is just a guessing game without repro code.  The non-obvious failure mode is when your UnhandledDispatcherExceptionHandler itself fell over on an exception.

Comment: If my UnhandledDispatcherExceptionHandler itself fell over on an exception I'd see this in the stacktrace I guess.

Comment: I have tried debugging without setting `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += UnhandledDispatcherExceptionHandler` which means that no dispatcher exception handler is set. Then I saw in the debugger that the event function was indeed null. This makes me think the Dispatcher instance is the correct one and there is another reason why it does not fire the dispatcher exception handler function but fires the domain exception handler directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that the instance is indeed the very same. So you always get the same instance when accessing `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` on the same thread.

A fix to make the dispatcher `UnhandledException` event fire was not to use `Invoke` but `BeginInvoke`. For a yet to me unknown reason exception beening thrown in an action/delegate executed with the dispatcher `Invoke` will not be able to be handled by the dispatchers `UnhandledException` event handler.

**Edit**

The solution with `BeginInvoke` is:

```
Action exception = () =>
{
    throw new Exception("myExceptionText");
};
myDispatcherInstance.BeginInvoke(exception);
```